# Using weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits for multilabel sparse classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel classification problem where each tuple in the training data set is labeled with one or more class and the number of classes in the data set is large ~500, resulting in sparse target vectors as

> [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0, ...].

I am using Keras with Tensorflow backend to build the classifier, my question is: Is it suitable to use the `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` as a loss function with sigmoid layer for classification? And how to set the pos_weight value to account for the matrix sparsity (i.e. give higher weights to 1's in the target matrix)?

I have a problem understanding how the function `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` works and its relation with precision and recall.